# Global Objects between Activities

Tags: java, android, global-variables

at the moment i'm working on an android app, but i've encountered a problem which i cannot solve. I have 2 activities. In one of them i define an ArrayList as public static. This list is used as content for a listview. in that other activity i want to edit items of that specific list or rather delete them.

Problem: 
on my samsung galaxy S II it works fine (Android version 4.0.4), but on other devices, like SGSIII (4.1 i think) there is a problem with synchronizing that list. so basically if that second activity finishes and returns to the first, all changes seem to be undone...

here is the code of the update function of the listview in the first activity; the changes are not recognized in this method:

```
private void updateList() { 

    String[] values = new String[hatCommandList.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length;i++) {             

        values[i] = ((Command)hatCommandList.get(i)).getRealCommand();

    }           
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);     
    ListViewSentCommands.setAdapter(adapter);       
}
```

as you can see, nothing special. and here the code of the 2nd activity in which i edit the "hatCommandList":

```
public void onClick(View v) {               
    SettingsActivity.hatCommandList.remove(position);                       
    finish();

}
```

"position", which is used to point at a position in the list obviously, contains the right value, i checked it already.

Anyway, i hope you can tell me why it works on some device and why it doesnt on some...

Greetings and thanks in advance,
Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this...

```
SettingsActivity.hatCommandList.remove(position);
```

Most importantly DO NOT create `public` objects or methods in an `Activity` and attempt to use them from any other Android application component - an `Activity` is a special case class which has a life-cycle and should not be treated like a 'normal' Java class.

If you want to share data in this way then I would recommend you create a POJO helper class and hold the `ArrayList` there. The second `Activity` can then make changes and when the first `Activity` resumes, have it check for data changes and refresh the adapter.

Comment: ok thank you very much. but i still can or rather have to use public static methods or objects right? because otherwise i wouldn't have access to that object in other activities right?

Comment: @timothy3001 : Yes, `public` and `public static` methods and objects are perfectly fine in Android for POJOs and even when extending various Android classes just not the `Activity` class. The fact that the `Activity` life-cycle is managed by the OS itself means it is not designed to be directly accessible from other application components and, as you have found out, attempting to do so will cause unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: well, it's still not working. i created an extra class which has an "public static ArrayList<Command> CommandList" in that class. but the problem remains. i will try to implement static and synchronized methods in that class to obtain the list and set the list, maybe this works out.. i just don't understand why those activities are not synchronized. It seems as if the first activity which is paused because of that second activity does not recognizie the changes and simply uses the old list, even if i wrote the data to an external class.is it possible to make the activity refresh it's resources

Comment: @timothy3001 : If you change the data in the source for an `ArrayAdapter`, you need to call its `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. This should trigger a refresh of the `ListView` contents.

Comment: i think misunderstood something. i'm using and ArrayList AND an ArrayAdapter. everytime i use that updateList method, the ArrayAdapter is recreated.
In addition: i used Logcat to obtain the length of that list when i just removed one object from the list (length was 16 after that) and also implemented that into the updatelist command in the first activity which is called as soon as it resumes. and their i get the length 17 again, which is the old state... :/ really odd, but thank you so far

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize your list: [how to create Synchronized arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814325/how-to-create-synchronized-arraylist)

Probably your running into a race condition.

Comment: This won't help. The OP's problem is related to the fact an Android `Activity` is a special case class and attempting to access `public static` fields or methods will fail most of the time due to the `Activity` life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem:

when the first activity is started, it reads data from a file into that list. that happens in the onCreate function.

The problem is now, that on my SGSII device with android 4.0.4 the focus resumes to the first activity when i finish the second without problems.

BUT on the SGSIII with 4.1 the onCreate method is used once again, even though it actually only resumes. At the moment i have no idea why, but that's a problem which can be solved i guess.

maybe you can give me some tips why the developer of android sdk did change and how i can stop that.

PS: i'm calling the startActivityForResult method to start the 2. activity and also the onActivityResult function.

Comment: interesting fact: even though you close apps by calling finish(), the values of the global variables are kept a while. so if i start the app again, it still uses those values. I'm not really sure if i appreciate this or not^^