# Stack Overflow in Java with the Stack implementation in Collections-Java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have a question which is related to the Stack implementation in the Collections framework in Java.

1. I can see from the implementation that the size of the Stack can grow. Does this mean that a `StackOverflowError` can never occur and eventually the Stack reaches a size and an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs?
2. From googling I found that the `Vector` class is deprecated since it synchronizes each and every operation as Jon Skeet pointed out here: [Is Java Vector deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

So, after this is there any real life scenario where I would use this Java class? I don't want to synchronize on each and every operation and want to synchronize on a bunch of operations. Can somebody give a real life situation/example.

Comment: `StackOverflowError` is thrown when the call stack grows too large, and for no other reason. The data structure known as `Stack` is different.

Comment: A stackoverflow can definitely occur. As for a use case for vector, I'm hard pressed to think of one

Comment: Note the the API doc of `java.util.Stack` says: "A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class."

Comment: @Jesper: your comment is THE answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack, the data structure, which goes by `java.util.Stack`, can grow. The method call stack in Java, however, cannot. It thus can overflow, invoking a `StackOverflowError`. This occurs primarily when dealing with recursion, but can occur elsewhere if you're not too careful.

There is an important distinction here between `java.util.Stack` and the java method call stack. One holds an array of generics, and the other is inherent to the JVM. The latter is used when a method exits to return to the previous method.

I've never heard of anyone unintentionally overflowing the JVM's stack, unless they were working on recursion.

Don't use `Vector`. There are much better classes out there. You can also just use an `ArrayList` and [keep its access synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814325/how-to-create-synchronized-arraylist).

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to explain that the call stack doesn't have anything to do with `java.util.Stack`, and that `StackOverflowError` doesn't have anything to do with `java.util.Stack`.

Comment: Got confused between call stack and the Stack data structure.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't use `java.util.Stack`, just like you shouldn't use `Vector` - they are both legacy collection classes which were replaced by `Deque` and `ArrayList` since Java version 1.2. Note that `Stack`'s API documentation says:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

Note that `StackOverflowError` extends `Error`, not `Exception` or `RuntimeException`. Errors are only thrown if there's some internal error in the JVM - they are not normally thrown by Java classes.

`StackOverflowError` is thrown only when the method call stack overflows; it does not have anything to do with `java.util.Stack`.

As you can see in the API documentation of `StackOverflowError`:

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowError` has nothing to do with `java.util.Stack`. The `java.util.Stack` will grow as long as there is free memory, or `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

In new applications, there is no need to use either `Vector` or `Stack`. Use `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque`. You rarely need thread safety provided by `Vector`, and if you do, use `Collections.synchronizedList` or `LinkedBlockingDeque`. However, since HotSpot JVM 1.6, this is not a problem any more, see for example here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/