# Java synchronized statement

Tags: java, synchronization, reentrantlock, synchronized-block

I need a threadsafe arraylist like this.

```
public class BookingList {

  private List<Booking> bookings;

  public BookingList() {
      bookings = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Booking>());
  }

  @Override
  public void addBooking(Booking booking)
  {
    synchronized (bookings) {
        bookings.add(booking);
    }   
  }

  @Override
  public void removeBooking(Booking booking)
  {
    synchronized (bookings) {
        bookings.remove(booking);
    }   
  }
}
```

According to java doc, when using Collections.synchronizedList one needs to synchronize each access to the list. I'm not sure whether my synchronized blocks will do this?

1. Is my use of synchronized blocks equivalent to

   ```
   ...
   public synchronized void addBooking(Booking booking) {
     bookings.add(booking);
   }
   ```
2. Should I use a ReentrantLock like this

   ```
   private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   public void addBooking(Booking booking) {
     try {
       lock.lock;
       bookings.add(booking);
     } finally {
       lock.release();
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: in this case: yes it is!

Comment: U can refer this link it will solve your problem [click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814325/how-to-create-synchronized-arraylist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to synchronize **simple operations** like **add** or **remove** because this is handled internally by the implementation and this is precisely why you use them: to avoid handling the synchronization yourself

But for **composite operations** like **iterations** or **multiple removal** that are out of the scope of the internal synchronization you must provide your own locking mechanism.

Comment: But then I have both an add method without synchronizing and a method that makes some sort of iteration. Then I only do synchronize on the iteration method. How can Java know that the synchronization of the add and iteration-method is the same? To clarify: I see that 2 different threads cannot call "add" simultaneously, but can one thread call add and the other the iteration.method?

Comment: If you synchronize on the whole list you should not have any issue: `synchronized(bookings){ // iterate ... }` because both the *add* method and your iteration will use the same lock.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1:

```
public synchronized void addBooking(Booking booking) {
   bookings.add(booking);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void addBooking(Booking booking) {
   synchronized (this){
       bookings.add(booking);
   }
}
```

2: for your example you should not use `ReentrantLock`. Calling methods of a list that has been initialized with `Collections.synchronizedList()` is thread-safe, no further `synchronized` or other locking mechanisms have to be used. For the rest see @Pragmateek's answer.

Comment: this.class should be this :)

Comment: True. I changed it. `this.class` will be used for static methods.