# Conccurent Modification and Synchronization of arraylists

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

This question is more about asking if my way of doing something is the "correct" way or not. I have some program that involves constantly updating graphical components. To that effect, I have the method below.

```
public void update(){
    for (BaseGameEntity movingEntity : movingEntityList) {
        ((MovingEntity)movingEntity).update();
    }
}
```

Essentially, the class containing this method has a list of all graphical objects that need updating and it loops through, calling their respective update methods.

The issue comes when I have to add new entities or remove current entities from this list. The addition and removal of entities is handled by a different thread, and as you can guess, this results in a Concurrent Modification Exception if I try to add/remove entities while also looping through and updating their graphical components.

My ad hoc solution was to simply throw a try-catch block around this and just ignore any concurrent modification exceptions that crop up - in effect, not updating at that specific time. This does exactly what I want and no problems occur.

```
public void update(){
    try{
        for (BaseGameEntity movingEntity : movingEntityList) {
            ((MovingEntity)movingEntity).update();
        }
    }catch(ConcurrentModificationException e){
            //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

However, my question is, is this a "proper" way of handling this issue? Should I perhaps be doing something akin to what is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814325/how-to-create-synchronized-arraylist)? What is the "correct" way to handle this issue, if mine is wrong? I'm not looking specifically for ways to make my arraylist thread safe such as through synchronized lists, I'm specifically asking if my method is a valid method or if there is some reason I should avoid it and actually use a synchronized list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way would be to synchronize the list with [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29):

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized (list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

If you are traversing way more than the number of times you update your list, you can also use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

If you don't mind occasional missing updates (or if they happen way too infrequently for the price of synchronization), your way is fine.

Comment: As stated, my program runs just fine as I have it. I do technically miss a few updates, but additions and removals are so small it doesn't matter. So my main questions is if I should be worrying about synchronizing if my way already works.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a "proper" way of handling this issue?

If you do not mind getting an increase of concurrency at the expense of dropping the updates on error, then the answer is "yes". You do run the risk of not completing an update multiple times in a row, when significant additions and removals to the list happen often.

On the other hand, when the frequency of updates is significantly higher than the frequency of adding/removing an object, this solution sounds reasonable.

> Should I perhaps be [using `synchronized`]?

This is also a viable solution. The difference is that an update would no longer be able to proceed when an update is in progress. This may not be desirable when the timing of calls to `update` is critical (yet it is not critical to update everything on every single call).

Comment: Depending on `ConcurrentModificationException` does not look like a good option to me, the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) states "... it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness"

Comment: @vanOekel With this solution, he is not *depending* on the `ConcurrentModificationException`, he is just *ignoring* it (and this can be done safely **in this specific case**)

Comment: @vanOekel The doc means something else - a program that *expects* this exception to be thrown in specific situations, to which the program reacts. OP's solution, on the other hand, chooses to *ignore* this exception, which is different from relying on the exception for correctness. In fact, OP's code would happily remain correct if this exception is never thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Some people consider it as a duplicate of all the generic synchronization questions. I think this is not the case. You are asking for a very specific constellation, and whether your solution is "OK", in this sense.

Based on what you described, the actual goal seems to be clear: You want to quickly and concurrently iterate over the entities to call the `update` method, and avoid any synchronization overhead that may be implied by using `Collections#synchronizedList` or similar approaches.

Additionally, I assume that the main idea behind the solution that you proposed was that the `update` calls have to be done very often and as fast as possible, whereas adding or removing entities happens "rarely".

<sup>So, adding and removing elements is an *exception*, compared to the regular operations ;-)</sup>

And (as dasblinkenlight already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466510/3182664)) for such a setup, the solution of catching and ignoring the `ConcurrentModificationException` is reasonable, **but** you should be aware of the consequences.

It might happen that the `update` method of **some** entities is called, and then the loop bails out due to the `ConcurrentModificationException`. You should be **absolutely sure** that this does not have undesirable side-effects. Depending on what `update` actually does, this might, for example, cause some entities to move faster over the screen, and others to not move at all, because their `update` calls had been missed due to several `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`. This may be particularly problematic if adding and removing entities is **not** an operation that happens rarely: If one thread constantly adds or removes elements, then the last elements of the list may never receive an `update` call at all.

---

<sub>If you want some "justification by example": I first encountered this pattern in the [JUNG Graph Library](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), for example, in the [SpringLayout](http://jung.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jung/jung/src/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/SpringLayout.java?revision=1.23&view=markup) class and others. When I first saw it, I cringed a little, because at the first glance it looks horribly hacky and dangerous. But here, the justification is the same: The process has to be as fast as possible, and modifications to the graph structure (which would cause the exception) are rare. Note that the JUNG guys actually do *recursive calls* to the respective method when the `ConcurrentModificationException` happens - simply because they can't always assume the method to be called constantly by another thread. **This**, in turn, can have nasty side-effects: If another thread does constant modifications, and the `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown *each time when the method is called*, then this will end with a `StackOverflowError`... But this is not the case for you, fortunately.</sub>

Comment: This is a very good point and explains my intentions well. To your last remark about only updating some entities. I'm not 100% sure that would be the case. When the error is thrown, it specifically addresses the `for ...` line, not the line calling the update method. This makes me think it realizes it cannot loop over the list at all as it is being used by another thread and simply doesn't do the loop at all. However I'm not certain on this idea, that was just my impression.

Comment: @zephyr The point is: You don't know *when* the exception will be thrown. If the list contains 10 elements, then the `for` loop might handle the first 5 elements. Then, another thread modifies the list, and the `for` loop breaks out with a `C.M.Exception`. The next time when `update` is called, it may again only update the first 5 elements, and again be interrupted by an exception...